# PHP Paypal Subscription Parameters

Tags: php, paypal, subscription

dear experts,

I'd like to add a VIP option on my website through subscription. Like an already existing member pay a monthly fee to gain features.

So I tried to use the paypal subscribtion button but I don't get how I can pass parameters like the account id to give him access.

I added variables but in the code they gave me, there is not way to change it :

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="DUFC7HMH4RRJU">
<input type="image"src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Also I'm not familiar with the Paypal API, is there a way to do what I want easily ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to with a hosted button.  You'll need to go into the button editor and disable the option to save the button at PayPal.  This will give you back button code with the parameters actually embedded in the code.

Then you can include the "custom" parameter and populate it with the value of your record ID that you need to track.  That same value will back in the custom parameter of IPN so you can update your database accordingly.

A better, more secure option would be to go with the Express Checkout API.  This will require some actual programming, though.  If you're working with PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It'll make that very simple for you.

If you decide to give that a try I can answer any other questions you have about it.

Comment: Hey, this seems to be the good solution, I just need confirmation on some things. From what I've understood, I have to make a form where my users will fill basic informations such as their BillingAddress, Credit card code etc (so it's no longer done by paypal ?). After I gather this information I just need to fill the arrays with them like in CreateReccurringPaymentsProfile.php sample and Paypal will do the transaction. And then according to the answer given stored in $PayPalResult I can promote / demote my users right ?

Comment: Well, in order to process cards directly within CRPP you'd have to sign up for Payments Pro and add the Recurring Payments feature to it.  There are monthly fees associated with that.